# A question on self-adjointness of the shape operator

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives

In the book Elementary Differential Geometry of Christian Bar, CUP, on the page 108, of the proof of theorem 3.5.5, the author wrote:

Theorem: Let $S ⊂ \mathbb{R}^3$ be an orientable regular surface with Wein-
garten map $W_p : T_pS\rightarrow T_pS$, $p ∈ S$. Then $W_p$ is self-adjoint with respect to the first fundamental form.

Proof: Let $N$ be the unit normal field of $S$ that induces the Weingarten
map, $W_p = −d_pN$. We choose a local parametrisation $(U, F, V)$ at $p$ and set
$u := F^{-1}( p)$.

As $N$ is perpendicular to $S$ everywhere, we have

$<\dfrac{\delta F}{\delta u^{i}}(u+te_j), N(F(u+te_j))>=0$

Differentiate the above equation, w.r.t $t$ we have

$\dfrac{d}{dt}<\dfrac{\delta F}{\delta u^{i}}(u+te_j), N(F(u+te_j))>|_{t=0}=0$

$=<\dfrac{d}{dt}\dfrac{\delta F}{\delta u^{i}}(u+te_j)|_{t=0}, N(p)>+<\dfrac{\delta F}{\delta u^i}(u), d_pN\circ D_uF(e_j)>=0$

My question is how can we deduce the second line from the first line after differentiate?

Please help me in a precise way.

Thanks.

**EDIT**: **May be you do not really understand my problem, I know that this is the Leibniz rule for inner product, but I cant understand how did they get the following equation from the above condition:**

$<\dfrac{d}{dt}\dfrac{\delta F}{\delta u^{i}}(u+te_j)|_{t=0}, N(p)>+<\dfrac{\delta F}{\delta u^{i}}(u+te_j), \dfrac{d}{dt}N(F(u+te_j))>$

$=<\dfrac{d}{dt}\dfrac{\delta F}{\delta u^{i}}(u+te_j)|_{t=0}, N(p)>+<\dfrac{\delta F}{\delta u^i}(u), d_pN\circ D_uF(e_j)>$

Comment: Chain rule with the fact that $ u = F^{-1}(p)$

Comment: @Jeb: So if we take the derivative at $t=0$, we also set $t=0$ in $F(u+te_j)$ and $N(F(u+te_j))$?